# Option or command for finding whether a file is empty

Tags: command-line, files

Is there a command that allows finding out whether or not a file contains something?

I tried with `ls`' size option (`ls -lsh`) but it does not show me the empty files because the files/folders have no size.

Comment: Well, if the file size is zero, there's nothing inside the file. Isn't that right ?

Comment: @Serg yeah man thats what i mean , can u help me with this?

Comment: can you please accept kos's answer as the correct one ? I need to remove mine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could analyse a file by the size using `du` command.

```
$> du Desktop/datasheet-3347.pdf                                
3564    Desktop/datasheet-3347.pdf
```

However, there's a small catch. What do we mean by the empty file ? Be aware that there are files with non-printable characters. Here's an example:

```
$> touch myFile.txt                                                            
$> echo '' > myFile.txt
$> du myFile.txt
4   myFile.txt
```

Look ! I've echoed empty space into the file, and yet it reports some size in bytes ? how can that be ?! Well, we've still written a single newline to the file.

As shown in [this brilliant answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62051/85039), files on disks are in chunks of 4096 bytes. When we write just a few bytes to the disk, the operating system *still* allocates a chunk of 4096 bytes. So technically file here is empty from human-readable point of view, and yet - it contains bytes.

We can create reference to a file , which will be 0 bytes, but once we try to fill it with any data, we'll give it 4096 bytes

```
$> touch myFile2.txt                                                           
$> du myFile2.txt
0   myFile2.txt
```

[But why directory is 4096 bytes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77/85039) ?  directories are sort of lists. Once you create a directory, even empty one, it holds information (for those interested in C programming language, that's dirent structure , which contains inode number, record length, type, and name; lookup dirent.h).
So even though directory may not have files, it will contain information about itself.

Comment: Serg, thats not right..FS stores data as blocks on disk and minimum block size for ext is 4K, not 512B..512B could be the physical sector size IIRC..

Comment: `du` always reporting in 4K chunks on my system..`du -b` shows the actual file size in bytes, not how much space it has taken on disk..try plain `du`..

Comment: I have no complaint over your selection of `du -b`..i am saying the part you have written about block size on disk is wrong....`/sys` is provided by kernel and is a `tmpfs` (resides on memory), you should see the files as zero sized as `sysfs` should not show the size of any file on `/sys` as it depends on the time of read..

Comment: I think that your example is confusing, especially the part *I've echoed empty space into the file* which is wrong: `echo ''` has written a new line because the `-n` option has not been used. It can be confusing for people who don't know how `echo` works. Can you please find an explicit example?

Comment: @A.L. i was trying to address the definition of empty file. New user may not realize that even though a file contains no printable text, it still has data. I will be making an edit to the answer later.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `test` with `-f` and `! -s`, which will return `0` in case of an existing empty regular file or `1` otherwise:

```
-f FILE
    FILE exists and is a regular file
-s FILE
    FILE exists and has a size greater than zero
```

```bsh
test -f file -a ! -s file && printf 'File exists and is empty.\n'
```

Or using a more common syntax:

```bsh
[ -f file -a ! -s file ] && printf 'File exists and is empty.\n'
```

```bsh
$ touch empty
$ printf '\n' >non_empty
$ test -f file -a ! -s empty && printf 'File exists and is empty.\n'
File exists and is empty.
$ test -f file -a ! -s non_empty && printf 'File exists and is empty.\n'
$
```

You could add a function to `~/.bashrc` for convenience:

```bsh
is_empty() { test -f file -a ! -s file && printf 'File exists and is empty.\n'; }
```

Or using a more common syntax:

```bsh
is_empty() { [ -f file -a ! -s file ] && printf 'File exists and is empty.\n'; }
```

```bsh
$ touch empty
$ printf '\n' >non_empty
$ is_empty empty 
File exists and is empty.
$ is_empty non_empty 
$
```

Comment: Since `-s` is also false if the file doesn't exist, I'd suggest using `-s` on its own to test for a nonempty file, and `[ -f "$1" -a ! -s "$1" ]` to test specifically for an existing empty file, rather than `! -s` on its own.

Comment: (perhaps `-e` instead of -`f`, but it's usually only meaningful to talk about the size of regular files.)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `stat`:

```
$ touch file
$ stat --format '%F' file
regular empty file
$ echo 'a' > file
$ stat --format '%F' file
regular file
```

Answer (score 0):

...or this:

```
find /dir/to/file -maxdepth 1 -name file_name -empty
```